# How to make a terminal node with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

My Professor is asking that we format our DFAs to include terminal nodes that look like this, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it

[image: example]

My Question is how do I make the concentric circles on the terminal q1?

Here is what I've done so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=white, very thick, minimum size=0.5in}]
\node[roundnode](q1) {$q_1$};
\node[roundnode, right= of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\path[thick,-to] (q1) edge [bend left] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$0$} (q1)
                 (q2) edge [loop above] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q2) edge [bend left] node[below] {$0$} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces:

[image: my code]

which is close enough for all of the credit, except for the concentric circles on q1, how do I do that? **(Please not the assignment is not on my LaTex skills, but the diagram I am drawing, so this question is not a plea for somebody to do my homework)**

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that makes use of the `xnode/.style={...}` property, I'd like to add a different type of node called `terminalnode` that, here's an example of the code for what I mean:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=white, very thick, minimum size=0.5in}, 
                    terminalnode/.style={...}]
\node[terminalnode](q1) {$q_1$};
\node[roundnode, right= of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\path[thick,-to] (q1) edge [bend left] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$0$} (q1)
                 (q2) edge [loop above] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q2) edge [bend left] node[below] {$0$} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is that possible, and if so, then how do I do it?

### Edit

Per Request, here is the entire file I'm working with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}      % real numbers
\newcommand{\Naturals}{\mathbb{N}}   % natural numbers
\newcommand{\Integers}{\mathbb{Z}}   % integer numbers
\newcommand{\Rationals}{\mathbb{Q}}  % rational numbers
\newcommand{\Complexes}{\mathbb{C}}  % complex numbers

% math symbols

\newcommand{\IFF}{\mbox{$\Longleftrightarrow$}}    % biimplication
\newcommand{\THEN}{\mbox{$\Rightarrow$}}           % implication

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=white, very thick, minimum size=0.5in}]
\node[roundnode](q1) {$q_1$};
\node[roundnode, right= of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\path[thick,-to] (q1) edge [bend left] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$0$} (q1)
                 (q2) edge [loop above] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q2) edge [bend left] node[below] {$0$} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @TobiBS I gotchu, see my edit above.

Comment: There's the tikz library automata that has pre-defined styles for this ( `accepting` iirc).

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `double` option which draws the double lines.
I marked the changes with `%<--`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}      % real numbers
\newcommand{\Naturals}{\mathbb{N}}   % natural numbers
\newcommand{\Integers}{\mathbb{Z}}   % integer numbers
\newcommand{\Rationals}{\mathbb{Q}}  % rational numbers
\newcommand{\Complexes}{\mathbb{C}}  % complex numbers

% math symbols

\newcommand{\IFF}{\mbox{$\Longleftrightarrow$}}    % biimplication
\newcommand{\THEN}{\mbox{$\Rightarrow$}}           % implication

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=white, very thick, minimum size=0.5in}]
\node[roundnode,double](q1) {$q_1$};%<-- add "double" option
\node[roundnode, right= of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\path[thick,-to] (q1) edge [bend left] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$0$} (q1)
                 (q2) edge [loop above] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q2) edge [bend left] node[below] {$0$} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this works, I found a better solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `automata` package, as specified by TeXnician, which includes classes, `state`, and `accepting` which do exactly what I'm asking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, automata} %<--

\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}      % real numbers
\newcommand{\Naturals}{\mathbb{N}}   % natural numbers
\newcommand{\Integers}{\mathbb{Z}}   % integer numbers
\newcommand{\Rationals}{\mathbb{Q}}  % rational numbers
\newcommand{\Complexes}{\mathbb{C}}  % complex numbers

% math symbols

\newcommand{\IFF}{\mbox{$\Longleftrightarrow$}}    % biimplication
\newcommand{\THEN}{\mbox{$\Rightarrow$}}           % implication

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}                           %<--
\node[state, accepting](q1) {$q_1$};          %<--
\node[state, right= of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};      %<--
\path[thick,-to] (q1) edge [bend left] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$0$} (q1)
                 (q2) edge [loop above] node[above] {$1$} (q2)
                 (q2) edge [bend left] node[below] {$0$} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```